# CRON Not Running Properly - Specifically with Sequential Commands

Tags: cron, wget

This is a very odd issue. Picture a fairly complex crontab with around 50 background jobs running, with about 30 or so of them running every minute and 20 running every 5 minutes to weekly.

Primarily the commands in the crontab run the wget command to trigger a script to run which does the heavy lifting.

For background, these commands within the crontab have been running perfectly for many many months - then all of a sudden some of the commands are having issues running - but failing silently.

For example imagine the setup, but hugely simplified;

```
* * * * * wget https://www.example.com/job-one

* * * * * wget https://www.example.com/job-two && wget https://www.example.com/job-three
```

What I'm seeing within the cron logs on the server is that everything is running every minute as you'd expect. But I don't always trust those, so I also have setup in the scripts behind job-one, job-two and job-three is a log to a database, which logs the **start time** and then once the job finishes this logs the **end time**. So you'd expect to see 3 records written to the database every minute.

And as I say, this has worked perfectly since setup many months ago.

All of a sudden this has started to not running **job-three**

Nothing has changed on the crontab, nothing has changed on the scripts one, two or three - and what is even stranger is that when you call the 3x URLs manually in the browser they all work perfectly as expected, no-one has logged onto the server in question and changed anything when checking the login logs - and even more strange is that when you run the following command at the command line on the server, this all works perfectly;

```
* * * * * wget https://www.example.com/job-two && wget https://www.example.com/job-three
```

I've restarted the cron daemon and I'm pending a full system restart (needs to be out of hours since this is a live box...which doesn't have any issues on the pre-prod environment).

Just posting the question to see if anyone has any ideas about other things to try and why this would happen. I've never known the crontab to behave like this. (I blame AWS...)

Answer (score 0):

I've had same issue before, in cron job '&' integrate the process of wget command into various process the URL link must be in "".

So try,

```
* * * * * wget "https://www.example.com/job-one"

* * * * * wget "https://www.example.com/job-two && wget https://www.example.com/job-three"
```